# Excecute script after defined value in variable without setTimeout in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, callback

I wanted to execute a script after define value in variable without setTimeout.

This is I am trying to do:

```
var sessionId;
function AddSessionID(e) {
    sessionId = e;
}

$(function(){
    alert(sessionId);
});
```

But I am getting value is undefined.

If I set a delay for this like:

```
$(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        alert(sessionId);
    }, 2000);
});
```

then I am getting proper value.

But I don't want to set delay for that. because session id is dynamic. it is depended to the server.

I need a call back.

This is really I wanted:

```
var sessionId;
    function AddSessionID(e) {
        sessionId = e;
    }

    $(function(){
        if (sessionId != undefined) {
            alert(sessionId);
    }
});
```

Comment: You define a function to set the value of `sessionId`, but you never call it...?

Comment: show us your complete code .

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Vipin/s56ryqo2/   this is i ma trying to do

Answer (score 0):

write a callback like this -

```
function AddSessionID(e) {
    sessionId = e;
    sessionIdReadyCallback();
}

function sessionIdReadyCallback(){
 alert(sessionId);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I wanted to execute inside a ready function.  Please check what I am trying to do...   http://jsfiddle.net/Vipin/s56ryqo2/

Comment: You haven't called `AddSessionID`,  have you ?

Comment: its called in some c++ code. that function executed from their.

Comment: I am getting session id inside the AddSessionID function like: 

function AddSessionID(e) {
console.log(e)
}

Comment: if `AddSessionId` function is getting called after your page is loaded, then there is no way you can get the `sessionId` value in document ready handler.you need to have some kind of callback like i have mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I would recommend some kind of "if function exists" to make the callback optional